# problem with image animation in viewDidAppear(), any advice?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, viewdidappear

I am trying to create an animation that scrolls through a series of images. The following code does not have any animation and only the last image of the series appears on the screen. How do I fix this animation?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        imageSelection(score: 50)
    }
func imageSelection(score: Int) {
        var myScore = score
        if score < 10 {
            myScore = 1
        }
        else if score < 20 && score > 10 {
            myScore = 2
        }
        else if score < 30 && score > 20 {
            myScore = 3
        }
        else if score < 40 && score > 30 {
            myScore = 4
        }
        else if score < 50 && score > 40 {
            myScore = 5
        }
        else if score == 50 {
            myScore = 6
        }
        for i in 1...myScore{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.cookieImage.image = UIImage(named: "rewardsCookie\(i)")
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not animating any animatable properties and you are running all `myScore` non-animations at once.

Comment: Also, what you are trying to achieve is not doable using `UIView` animation blocks. You'll have to compose an animation using `CAAnimation`. Keep in mind that `layoutIfNeeded()` only animates if there are changes in the constraints, and you don't have that in this snippet (at most will animate image size changes if you set the constraints correctly). If you want to have transition animations from one image to another (like fade-in fade-out, for example), you'll have to implement them.

Comment: @matt what would be an animatable property? and how do I run them separately?

Comment: @VladRusu can you provide an answer with how I would create an CAAnimaiton for this?

Comment: animatable view properties are listed in the UIView documentation; there is nothing about a UIImageView where merely setting the image is going to result in any kind of animation, you would have to write that animation "from scratch" using CABasicAnimation or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt said, you are not animating any animatable properties. You can achieve what you want to by using layer animations. Replace your `for` loop with the following code.

```
    var images = [CGImage]()
    for i in 1...myScore{
        images.append(UIImage(named: "rewardsCookie\(i)")!.cgImage!)
    }
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
    animation.values = images
    let delay = 3.0 // in case you need to delay your animation
    animation.duration = 5.0 // change to the total duration (ex: 0.5 * myScore)
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay
    self.cookieImage.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Note that for layer animations, you are not actually seeing the UIImageView, but a cached version of it. This is removed from the screen once the animation completes and the original layer shows itself again. So you will see the image that was visible on the `cookieImageView` before the animation began. In order to persist the last image, add the following line after the code above

```
    self.cookieImage.image = UIImage(named: "rewardsCookie\(myScore)")
```

For more information go through [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying do a "flip book" animation where you flip between a sequence of images? The easy way to do that is with UIImageView animation. See the UIImageView class reference in Xcode for more information (see the section titled "Animating a Sequence of Images".